# Programmatically power off the windows machine immediately

Tags: windows, power-off

Can I create a simple program to power off the windows machine immediately? I would like the behavior to be like pressing PWR OFF/RESET button. So the power is cut off immediately. Is there any way to send a software interrupt to motherboard to make this happen?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to power down the computer from a freestanding environment?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145569/how-to-power-down-the-computer-from-a-freestanding-environment)

Comment: you might corrupt files that way

Comment: @Paul R - Windows is not a freestanding environment. No dup.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this in assembly language like MASM.
Here's small tutorial from Microsoft: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/68805

Also you can try to execute `int 19h` assembly command.

But I'm not sure if theese methods will work under win2k and later.
To get them working you should create a driver then.

Comment: Thank you. I've tried both C code and assembly code but it didn't work on my machine. It seems that neither I can't set bios pointer to the desired address nor I can't directly jump to the reboot address. My machine is running windows xp service pack 3.

Comment: The link is for MS-DOS. Not Windows 3.11, 95, or any other Microsoft OS from the last two decades. Note that is says "Works on 8086, and some 80286/80386 machines" !