# X86 instructions to power off computer in real mode?

Tags: assembly, x86, dos

Is there any sequence of x86 instructions in real mode that will power off (not reboot) the machine?  I have an old computer with MS-DOS still on it and I'm curious about it.

This question is specifically about real mode, not protected mode or 64-bit long mode.

Comment: I think this question might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145569/how-to-power-down-the-computer-from-a-freestanding-environment

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [this](http://wiki.osdev.org/Shutdown) article on OSDev, you can either use the ACPI or the APM interfaces. ACPI seems overcomplicated, as you can see in [this article](http://forum.osdev.org/viewtopic.php?t=16990) while APM is much simpler. I'll report the basic steps as they appear [here](http://wiki.osdev.org/APM):

1)  Installation check, to see if APM is supported:

```
mov ah,53h            ;this is an APM command
mov al,00h            ;installation check command
xor bx,bx             ;device id (0 = APM BIOS)
int 15h               ;call the BIOS function through interrupt 15h
jc APM_error          ;if the carry flag is set there was an error
                      ;the function was successful
                      ;AX = APM version number
                          ;AH = Major revision number (in BCD format)
                          ;AL = Minor revision number (also BCD format)
                      ;BX = ASCII characters "P" (in BH) and "M" (in BL)
                      ;CX = APM flags (see the official documentation for more details)
```

2) Disconnect to any existing interface:

```
;disconnect from any APM interface
mov ah,53h               ;this is an APM command
mov al,04h               ;interface disconnect command
xor bx,bx                ;device id (0 = APM BIOS)
int 15h                  ;call the BIOS function through interrupt 15h
jc .disconnect_error            ;if the carry flag is set see what the fuss is about. 
jmp .no_error

.disconnect_error:       ;the error code is in ah.
cmp ah,03h               ;if the error code is anything but 03h there was an error.
jne APM_error            ;the error code 03h means that no interface was connected in the first place.

.no_error:
                         ;the function was successful
                         ;Nothing is returned.
```

3) Connect to the real mode interface (01h):

```
;connect to an APM interface
mov ah,53h               ;this is an APM command
mov al,[interface_number];see above description
xor bx,bx                ;device id (0 = APM BIOS)
int 15h                  ;call the BIOS function through interrupt 15h
jc APM_error             ;if the carry flag is set there was an error
                         ;the function was successful
                         ;The return values are different for each interface.
                         ;The Real Mode Interface returns nothing.
                         ;See the official documentation for the 
                         ;return values for the protected mode interfaces.
```

4) Enable power management for all devices:

```
;Enable power management for all devices
mov ah,53h              ;this is an APM command
mov al,08h              ;Change the state of power management...
mov bx,0001h            ;...on all devices to...
mov cx,0001h            ;...power management on.
int 15h                 ;call the BIOS function through interrupt 15h
jc APM_error            ;if the carry flag is set there was an error
```

5) Finally, set the power state to off (03h):

```
;Set the power state for all devices
mov ah,53h              ;this is an APM command
mov al,07h              ;Set the power state...
mov bx,0001h            ;...on all devices to...
mov cx,[power_state]    ;see above
int 15h                 ;call the BIOS function through interrupt 15h
jc APM_error            ;if the carry flag is set there was an error
```

Comment: Tested on QEMU 2.0.0 Ubuntu 14.04: https://github.com/cirosantilli/x86-bare-metal-examples/blob/7cff2a3fc93a636f8e253892af212a30c5a58697/apm_shutdown2.S

Comment: @CiroSantilli六四事件法轮功纳米比亚威视 very interesting, thank you!

Comment: So what do you do when that last int15h returns success?

Comment: @konniskatt on my repo or with a custom setup? The one one my repo worked just now on Ubuntu 18.10, 2.12.0: `make; run apm_shutdown2`. If on my repo, open a bug report there with your OS and QEMU version.