# Shutdown in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86-16, shutdown, osdev, bios

I just started programming in assembly, I started with a simple program with a print, input and new line function. Then I wondered how to shutdown the machine and I found this function online:

```
shutdown:
    mov ax, 0x1000
    mov ax, ss
    mov sp, 0xf000
    mov ax, 0x5307
    mov bx, 0x0001
    mov cx, 0x0003
    int 0x15
```

This code works but I need to know why.

Comment: Check a manual: [INT 15/AX=5307H SET POWER STATE](http://www.techhelpmanual.com/38-int_15h_5307h__set_power_state.html).  It's an APM call to shut down the system.

Comment: `mov ax, 0x1000` `mov ax, ss` `mov sp, 0xf000` Are you sure you copied the code correctly? Loading AX twice is silly. Shouldn't it be: `mov ax, 0x1000` `mov ss, ax` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [X86 instructions to power off computer in real mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21463908/x86-instructions-to-power-off-computer-in-real-mode)

Comment: @SepRoland I literally do copy and paste

Comment: @x444556 The codes are different, on this page it's much more complicated. However, of this code I didn't understand only the first 4 lines:```mov ax, 0x1000```
    ```mov ax, ss```
    ```mov sp, 0xf000```
    ```mov ax, 0x5307```