# Shutdown OS in assembly

Tags: assembly, operating-system, shutdown

I'm writing a simple OS in assembly but I can't figure out how to shutdown the computer.

I've tried to use `hlt` like this

```
 .shutdown:
   mov si, msg_shutdown
   call print_string
   hlt
```

but it doesn't work. 
I know that `int 19h` will restart the computer but is there an interrupt for shutdown?

I'll appreciate some help. Thanks.

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/678458/shutdown-the-computer-using-assembly

Comment: This question doesn't help me at all, I saw it.

Comment: Which OS are you using for this?

Comment: I'm writing an OS and I want it to be able to shutdown.

Answer (score 1):

`hlt` only halts the CPU until an interrupt occurs.

```
cli
hlt
```

may do what you want. You might also wish to disable NMIs, but I think if we get a NMI we're in big trouble anyway. You might also want to leave interrupts enabled, and reboot if the user hits "esc" or some such, otherwise back to `hlt`. If you actually want to shut the power off... mmm, that's more complicated...

Edit: Re-reading your question, I guess you do want to shut the power off(?). Look around here: http://wiki.osdev.org/Shutdown

Comment: Usually you'd want to put `hlt` in a loop, especially if you leave interrupts enabled so ctrl+alt+del can still work.

Answer (score -1):

reboot :

```
reboot:
    jmp 0xffff:0000h
```

shutdown :

```
shutdown:
    mov ax, 5307h
    mov cx, 3
    mov bx, 1
    int 15h
```

halt :

```
halt:
    cli
    hlt
```

Comment: Unless you disable NMIs, you should put a loop around `cli` / `hlt`.

Comment: General protection fault happens on both reboot and shutdown.

Comment: That `int 15h` call is https://wiki.osdev.org/APM